# Can the classical action for an electron in constant magnetic field be periodically infinity for different values of time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, lagrangian-formalism, electrons, path-integral

In Feynman's book, 'Quantum Mechanincs and Path integral', the following problem is given (page no. 64):[image: prolem, page number 64]

Now, we know that $Kernel\propto e^{iS_{cl}/h}$ if $S$ is quadratic. Here, $S_{cl}$ refers to the classical action.

So, the problem in the book implies that for an electon moving in a constant magnetic feild, $S_{cl}=\frac{m}{2}\left[\frac{(z_{b}-z_{a})^{2}}{T}+\left(\frac{w/2}{\tan(wT/2)}\right)\left[(x_{b}-x_{a})^{2}+(y_{b}-y_{a})^{2}\right]+w(y_{b}x_{a}-x_{b}y_{a})\right]$

Now, this makes no sense because we can notice that for some values of $T$, $\tan(wT/2)$ will become zero, making the action infinity. Since the classical path of an electron in constant magnetic field is circular or helical, the expression for action that I am getting has no scope of infinities in it.

So, is the expression for $S_{cl}$ as given in the book above correct? If not, is not the expression for kernel as given in the book wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The motion in the $x$, $y$ plane follows a circle. Let this circle have radius $R$. The equation of motion follows from the Lorentz force

$$ \boldsymbol{F} = \frac{e}{c} \boldsymbol{v} \times \boldsymbol{B}. $$

The force is centripetal, so its magnitude is $mv^2/R$, and the equation of motion is

$$ \frac{m v^2}{R} = \frac{eBv}{c}. $$

Therefore the particle moves in the circle with velocity

$$ v = \frac{e B R}{m c}, $$

and the period for one cycle in the $x$, $y$ plane is

$$ \Delta t = \frac{2\pi R}{v} = \frac{2 \pi m c}{e B} = \frac{2\pi}{\omega}. $$

Integer multiples of this period are precisely the values of $T$ for which $\tan(\omega T/2) = 0$. Now consider the worrisome term in the classical action:

$$ \frac{\omega/2}{\tan(\omega T/2)} \left( (x_b - x_a)^2 + (y_b - y_a)^2 \right). $$

When $T = n\Delta t = 2\pi n/\omega$, this term does not necessarily diverge, because the particle has returned to its starting point where $x_a = x_b$ and $y_a = y_b$, so this term actually approaches the indeterminate form $0/0$.

To simplify this indeterminate form, let us choose coordinates such that $t_a = 0$ and $t_b = T$, and the motion takes the form

$$ x(t) = \cos(\omega t), \quad y(t) = \sin(\omega t). $$

Then

\begin{align}
(x_b - x_a)^2 + (y_b - y_a)^2 &= (\cos(\omega T)-1)^2 + \sin(\omega T)^2 \\ 
&= 2 - 2 \cos(\omega T).
\end{align}

Therefore the term in the action is

$$ \frac{\omega}{2} \frac{2 - 2 \cos(\omega T)}{\tan(\omega T/2)} = \omega\sin(\omega T), $$

which is finite for all $T$. The problem you identified at $T = 2\pi n/\omega$ is just a removable discontinuity, not an actual divergence.